# Postgres Listen/Notify As Message Queue

Tags: postgresql, event-notification, queue

Is there any way to use Postgres Listen/Notify feature to deliver a message to a channel and have only one listener consume this message?

The purpose for this is that I have multiple 'worker' apps all listening to the same Postgres channel. But I only want the work done once per message received through the notification channel.

If Listen/Notify is not the correct feature in Postgres, is there a seperate feature I should be using?

Ideally I would like to do this without using any additional extensions.

Answer (score 35):

According to [PostgreSQL documentation about `NOTIFY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html):

> The NOTIFY command sends a notification event together with an optional "payload" string to **each** client application that has previously executed LISTEN channel for the specified channel name in the current database. **Notifications are visible to all users**.

(emphasis mine)

This means you cannot do what you want **just with** `LISTEN/NOTIFY`. However, you can have both a table to store queued messages, `LISTEN/NOTIFY` to notify external applications that "there are new things in the message queue", and use some extra logic from these external applications so that only one consumes the message.

The strategy depicted in the article [What is SKIP LOCKED for in PostgreSQL 9.5?](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/) is probably the safest/easiest way to implement a **message queue** within PostgreSQL. Pay special attention to the "How SKIP LOCKED helps" part. Read also carefully one of their caveats:

> A queue implemented in the RDBMS will never match the performance of a fast dedicated queueing system, even one that makes the same atomicity and durability guarantees as PostgreSQL. Using SKIP LOCKED is better than existing in-database approaches, but you’ll still go faster using a dedicated and highly optimised external queueing engine.

This is specially important if the queue volume is high.

Comment: I wish I could award a bounty to the author of that article.  So extremely helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I did something like this a while back with good success, I used RabbitMQ and this plugin https://github.com/gmr/pgsql-listen-exchange

Basically RabbitMQ Connects to PostgreSQL and listens for the notify event, then you can use RabbitMQ to aggregate that message to as many queues as needed and have an app consuming each queue

Answer (score 0):

Using the raw feature itself it's more akin to pub/sub. But what you're looking for is a work queue. To implement a work queue, you'll have to have clients using LISTEN one-to-one with channel names, then the NOTIFY will only be sent to a specific channel name, not a singleton static channel name. You can keep track of the channel names with a table. When you get a message look for an "open" channel in this table, then call NOTIFY on that channel name with the message payload.

UPDATE: I wrote a blog post about this very topic: https://worlds-slowest.dev/posts/postgresql-message-queue/

I created a project to use LISTEN/NOTIFY as a message queue, with work queue semantics. See https://github.com/perfectsquircle/pg_mq

Like @joanolo mentions in [his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/171142/275348) it uses SKIP LOCKED to implement queuing between multiple consumers.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/196407)